# Arcade games in Apple IIc's ROM

Tags: apple-ii, rom, gaming, arcade

Is there a website where I can find the old games that where pre-installed in the Apple IIc ROM? When I could not get an OS disk, I could still have some fun with my Apple IIc by playing those arcade games from the ROM (space-invaders, …) and there was a shortcut that gave me access to the source code, too. Also, is there any corresponding emulator for modern PC/Mac computers?

Comment: Are you *sure* there were pre-installed arcade games in the original ROM? I just checked both the official ROM listing and a dump of v4, and couldn't find anything (and no source code, either). Maybe you had some special hardware?

Comment: Well, yes I am sure, things like the old space invaders, and many others. I highly doubt that it was some customized hardware....

Comment: If you actually find a ROM image with these, please post a link, I'd be very curious to see that.

Comment: There are no games in the Apple //c ROM. Memory is a funny thing - but not that memory! Possibly the machine you used had a hard drive.

Comment: @NickWestgate: I vaguely recollection the //c ROM containing something game-ish.  ROM chips come in power-of-two sizes, but the total amount of ROM required in the //c is not a power of two.  By the time it came out, the prices of different size ROM chips were such that manufacturing a machine with more ROM (though possibly not using it all) would likely have been cheaper than manufacturing one with exactly the required amount.

Comment: @supercat Then you need to provide proof. The ROMs are readily available on the internet. The four types (5 if you include the IIc+) are described here on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_IIc#Revisions).

Comment: Questions like this do not bother me.  However, how is this not like my question here?  http://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/1964/what-are-the-apple-ii-specific-books-written-since-2000  A question that could never be answered because it would be a list of websites vs. a list of books?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't remember any embedded games, but I would highly recommend Virtual II (http://www.virtualii.com/) for Apple II emulation.  Its free if used in a limited fashion, otherwise you need to buy a license, but it does just about everything you could possibly think of.

As far as a short-cut for access to the 'source code', the only thing I can think of is that you are asking for how to access the ROM monitor.  From the command prompt:

```
]CALL -151
```

This will drop you into the monitor, where you can query RAM address and disassemble whatever is in memory (RAM/ROM).  For example, after entering the ROM monitor you will get a * prompt.  You can type a memory address followed by the letter L (with no spaces) to list (disassemble) memory, like this:

```
*FF69L
```

More information regarding using the monitor can be found here: http://www.classiccmp.org/cini/pdf/Apple/Apple%20II%20(Redbook)%20Reference%20Manual%2030th%20Anniversary.pdf starting around page 68 or so.

Comment: What about [AppleWin](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppleWin)? It's free and open source ([Github](//GitHub.com/AppleWin/)), and emulates an Apple ][ e.

Comment: and MAME, while we're at it.

Answer (score 12):

I feel like you're remembering the Apple At Play disk that came with the Apple //c.  It had Lemonade Stand, Quick Quiz, and Space Quarks (more of a Galaxian clone than Space Invaders, but I didn't know Galaxian when I was young, so I compared it to Space Invaders, too).

[image: Space Quarks]
[image: Lemonade Stand]

On Windows 10, I use [AppleWin](https://github.com/AppleWin/AppleWin), which is really a //e emulator, but it has all the nostalgia of the //c I loved as a child. I used it to capture the screenshots above. I've never used a Mac, so I can't help you there.

And there used to be an online repository of all things Apple // called asimov.net.  There are still mirrors floating around the web.  I don't know how well they can be trusted, so I can't specifically recommend any site, but I did use an asimov mirror in order to obtain the pic of Space Quarks.

Also, [archive.org](https://archive.org/details/softwarelibrary_apple_games) lets you play ancient emulated games directly in the browser.

Comment: Right: that's the one!!! (+1). Any links, resources, emulators?

Comment: @alainlompo I added some links to resources I use, and one piece of information I can't recommend, but it's there for you to explore.